# How to append Parent and child div on div element in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I am newbie in angularjs. Here I added my requirement as image. In side my controller I need get selected element and in runtime in need to add div's based on the source will diced parent or child. help me on this

Example 1:-

```
before:-
  Username: <input type="text" name="user">
  Username1: <input type="text" name="user1">
After:-
    <div ><!-- 1st-->
      Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    Username1: <input type="text" name="user1">
    </div>
```

Example 2:-

```
Before:-
        <div ><!-- 1st-->
          Username: <input type="text" name="user">
        Username1: <input type="text" name="user1">
        </div>
After:-
        <div ><!-- 1st-->
          <div ><!-- 2nd-->
            Username: <input type="text" name="user">
            Username1: <input type="text" name="user1">
          </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You are certainly "seeing" things in a wrong way (meaning not very suitable for angular, it's not jQuery). Tell us what you want to achieve more in detail and we will be able to give answers or at least tails.

Comment: I added some more detail is it ok or need more?

Answer (score 1):

Go through this link. I have done in jquery. For angular replace $ with angular.element

https://plnkr.co/edit/GiY68oZdvj6IXYhgQwux?p=preview

```
var elems = $('.same').eq(4);
$( "#sam1" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
$('#sam2').siblings().wrapAll( "<div class='secondnew'></div>")
$('.same').siblings().eq(1).css('color', 'red');
$('.same').siblings().eq(2).css('color', 'red');
$('#sam3').nextUntil(elems).addBack().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea but works. Actually, both are same cases. You just need to edit the id's if there. Thats it

In first case get `parentDiv` with its children.
`document.getElementById('parentDiv');` with innerHTML and Children and store it in a varibale ex, `parentDiv`.
Next, create holder element to the above elements.

```
var holder = document.createElement('holder');
```

place this where you want and append the `parentDiv` as a child

```
holder.appendChild('parentDiv');
```

delete `parentDiv` from DOM.

Second case is also same. Just id's or attributes are matter here.

```
        var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
        var parentParent = document.createElement('div');
        parentParent.setAttribute('id', 'parentParent');
        document.body.appendChild(parentParent);
        parentParent.appendChild(parent);
```

find there lines in https://plnkr.co/edit/Y2cJrUGYcygvM9i6wKx5?p=preview index.html

Comment: how to add parent div for the element

Comment: can you share me some example in plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check it out. First case is done with that

Comment: I also updated the plunker as you want in first case